# Why I do not see my saved login/password in keychain?

Tags: ios, keychain

My iOS application has login/password prompt for its services. I can successfully save and load login/password data in the keychain.

But there is a problem: I do not see this login/password information in the keychain. There is a big list of other credentials in the keychain, but there are none which are saved from my application. Yes, they can be **loaded** from the keychain, but they are **not visible** in the keychain.

I have successfully saved and loaded logins/passwords both as `kSecClassInternetPassword` and `kSecClassGenericPassword` security classes. But anyway these passwords never appeared in global list of logins and passwords in the iOS keychain.

What should I do to see my saved logins and passwords in the iOS keychain list?

Comment: It’s not possible to view keychain entries on iOS at this time. The Passwords screen in Settings shows account credentials saved in Safari.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices you should use this instead if you want access to passwords in a way